# how to download xml files in android?

Tags: android

I'm New to android, I used following code for downloading XML files from FTP. It is working fine in Java. But in Android it is unable to connect to FTP it is giving following exception.

```
java.io.IOException: Unable to connect to server: Unable to retrieve file: 550
```

I have included internet permission tag in manifest file. How can I

`XML File(manifest file)`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

`Java Files`

```
        protected void testFTP() throws Exception {
        final String localfile = "/data/data/com.itwine/files/index.xml";
        final String targetfile = "index.xml";
        final String host = "ftp.qualityinaction.net/QIA/Questions/Airlines";
        final String user = "qualityinaction.net";
        final String password = "password";
        try
        {
             URL url = new URL("ftp://"+ user+ ":"+ password+ "@"+ host + "/"+
                     targetfile+ ";type=i");
                             URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();
                             urlc.setDoOutput(true);
                             // the following line throws "unable to connect to host {0}"
                             OutputStream os = urlc.getOutputStream();
                             FileInputStream is=  new FileInputStream(localfile);

                        byte[] buf= new byte[16384];
                        int c;
                        while (true) {
                                c= is.read(buf);
                                if (c<= 0)  break;
                                os.write(buf, 0, c);
                        }
                        os.close();
                        is.close();
                        urlc = null; // close
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Exception", e.toString());
        }

}
```

`Exception list*`

java.io.IOException: Unable to connect to server: Unable to retrieve file: 550

Comment: Just to point out you left your password hard coded in your question. Becareful if that is sensitive information.

Comment: I think 5** is a server side error.

Comment: but through browser i can able to access server, is this code works in android?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

The method you proposed now may not work with all servers, it's revised here (there is also a solution with using additional library):

[Download from ftp](http://androiddevcentral.com/source-code/10)

or I found how to do that with intent but I didn't test any of those solutions

[Download using intent](http://androiddevcentral.com/source-code/10)

Comment: Thanks For response,it will through a exception Not an HTTP connection after that it will not executing the  HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn  it will jumps to catch block how to fix this please help me

Comment: Show the code you have now and the full stack trace of the exception would be good.

Comment: full stack trace is (No explicit return value)

Comment: Thank you for response,Can u please tell me how to pass parameter those parameter values i mentioned in above code because yesterday i tried using this intent when i did startactivity finally it throws a exception please,

Comment: I pasted intent code with parameter please check those parameters are correct or what let me know, it's giving exception i will add exception in another cooment line

Comment: Exception i mentioned in stack overflow question please see and help me

Comment: I didn't read into those soluitons and unfortunately the one with intent is for a external program called AndFTP. So it probably won't work alone. Sorry. As for your first code (that with 550 error code), the 550 error code means that you don't have permission to download the file. So maybe your credentials are not valid?

Comment: In my first code if i copy full url path in my browser like(ie,mozilla) it will allow me to see those files in my browser so i think my credentials will be correct.

Comment: Maybe too much slashes? You have two at the end of host string and than add another one when constructing url?